# SQL Server NOLOCK with JOIN, Bulk load

Tags: sql-server, join, nolock

Following is the scenario I have:
I have a stored procedure that returns data by joining 4 tables. 
Twice in the middle of the day there is a bulk upload to **one** of the above 4 tables. The load continues for 10-15 minutes. I do not want the UI that invokes this stored procedure to freeze/block/slow down during this 10-15 minute window. I do not care about showing dirty/uncommitted data from the above tables. Following are my queries:

1. Do I need to use NOLOCK on just the table which is being loaded during the day OR NOLOCK needs to be added to all 4 tables of the join.
   For e.g.

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM Table1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK) --this is the table that will be bulk-loaded twice during the day
   INNER JOIN Table2 T2 WITH (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN Table3 T3 WITH (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN Table4 T4 WITH (NOLOCK)
   ```

   OR is this sufficient

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM Table1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK) --this is the table that will be bulk-loaded twice during the day
   INNER JOIN Table2 T2
   INNER JOIN Table3 T3
   INNER JOIN Table4 T4
   ```
2. If I add a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED at the beginning of the retrieval procedure and reset it back to READ COMMITTED at the end, will there be any difference?

Thanks

Vikas

Comment: @MartinSmith that is incorrect. Only a Sch_M lock blocks a read-uncommitted read-only query.

Comment: @SebastianMeine - You're right I thought it took an `IS` lock not a `SCH-S` lock.

Comment: Also keep in mind, SCH-M isn't just for schema changes. It can be taken for things like offline reindexing, truncates, and occasionally bulk inserts. See here for when SCH-M can be taken during a bulk insert in bulk or simple recovery model: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You only need to add `NOLOCK` for the tables that will be locked for prolonged periods of time, so adding `NOLOCK` to only `Table1` is sufficient.
2. If you set the isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`, you do not need to add `NOLOCK` at all, since it will be automatically applied to all queried tables. In other words you will create a situation similar to the first example in your question item 1 where `NOLOCK` is applied to all tables participating in the `SELECT`.

By the way, make sure you add `ON` conditions to your `INNER JOIN` clauses, because as presented they are not valid Transact-SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and concise answer Michael. Just what I was looking for. Reg the ON condition, yes, the above was semi-pseudo code. The actual JOINs do have ON conditions.